# joinging three tables in psql and keeping results according to group membership

Tags: join, psql

I am using psql and joined three tables A, B and C from table A.

For example resulting table is as follows:

```
+----+------+------+------+
| pk | a_id | b_id | c_id |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 |    5 |   12 |   16 |
|  2 |    5 |    7 |    8 |
|  3 |    5 |    6 |   21 |
|  4 |    8 |   12 |   16 |
|  5 |    8 |    3 |    9 |
|  6 |    9 |   11 |   32 |
|  7 |    9 |    8 |    2 |
+----+------+------+------+
```

I am trying to create c_id relations over a_id. In a_id there are three groups [5,8,9]. For example c_id=16 has a relation to a_id=[5,8], so c_id=[8,21,9,32] must be protected via a_id=[5,8]. And resulting table should look like as follows:

```
+----+------+------+------+
| pk | a_id | b_id | c_id |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 |    5 |   12 |   16 |
|  2 |    5 |    7 |    8 |
|  3 |    5 |    6 |   21 |
|  4 |    8 |   12 |   16 |
|  5 |    8 |    3 |    9 |
+----+------+------+------+
```

How can I write such a condition in join statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the join, you can write this query. I created your result table directly, and then I wrote a SQL query.

```
SELECT * from res
WHERE a_id in (SELECT distinct a_id
               FROM res
               WHERE c_id=16)
```

[image]